# how to detect if the click is outside of bootstrap model and call the fumction if click is outside of model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**I am try to call a function when mouse clicks out of bootstrap model.
please, give me idea.**

HERE IS THE IMAGE [image]

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: you can use window.onclick

Comment: I have no any coding @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: you are about to reach because windows.onclick will also called when i clicks on bootstrap model. i want to do it outside of click @NegiRox

Comment: then show your bootstrap modal code

Comment: it is very lengthy that can not colud not fix in comment @NegiRox

Comment: problem solved, i have added backdrop:static for the model but i want also even if backdrop static is added, and i click outside of model, i can call function @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read bootstrap official document https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-events
here is the list of different events

you can use this

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // do something...
})
```

Comment: right it worked, but i want also when i click outside of model then function is fired even if i have added backdrop

Comment: @HardikDavra can you share the code. I can't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: `$('#edit-modal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
});`